# What does the skull mean on the wheel of heal points?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

What does the skull mean on your point card in the heal points?  It goes to 12 and then the next is a skull.

Comment: You've turned it too far! You can't have more than 10 life without special abilities, and you can't have more than 12 with.

Answer (score 12):

The skull is actually indicating 0 Life Points (i.e. you are dead and eliminated from the game). This is made more explicit in the [Fifth Anniversary Edition rules](http://iellogames.com/downloads/KOT2-rulebook_EN.pdf):

[image]

In other words, the skull is one lower than 1 Life Point rather than one higher than 12. The fact that the skull and 12 are next to each other is only because this is a round wheel.